# Real Numbers - Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $a$, $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, and $a\neq b$, then there exist $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods $U$ of $a$ and $V$ of $b$ such that $U∩V = ∅$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a\neq b\implies \delta:=|a-b|>0\implies \left(a-\frac\delta2\;,\;a+\frac\delta2\right)\cap\left(b-\frac\delta2\;,\;b+\frac\delta2\right)=\emptyset$$

Comment: Can you elaborate somehow?

Comment: I really can't see anything to elaborate about...try to draw the above on a line representing the real line, and two points $\;\alpha,\beta\;$ on it and their distance $\;\delta\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=|a-b|$ be the distance between the two points.

Let $U$ be all points a distance strictly less than $\frac{1}{3}d$ away from $a$.

Let $V$ be all points a distance strictly less than $\frac{1}{3}d$ away from $b$.

Both $U,V$ are open, and any two points $x\in U, y \in V$ must be at least $\frac{1}{3}d$ away from each other, hence the two sets cannot intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r := d(a,b)/2$. Assume $x\in B(a,r) \cap B(b,r)$. Then $d(a,b)\leq d(a,x)+d(x,b) <2r=d(a,b)$. A contradiction.